# Weird runtime error while implementing a bubble sort in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

This snippet not only causes a runtime error, it makes FPC close if I run it using the debugger.

```
procedure sortplayersbyscore(var vAux:tplayers);

    procedure swap(var a:trplayers;var b:trplayers);

    var
        rAux:trplayers;

    begin
        rAux:=a;
        a:=b;
        b:=rAux;
    end;

var
    i,j:integer;
    sorted:boolean;

begin
    vAux:=playersarray;
    i:=1;
    sorted:=false;
    while (i <= MAXPLAYERS -1) and not sorted do
    begin
        j:=1;
        sorted:=true;
        while (j <= MAXPLAYERS -i) do
        begin
            if (vAux[j].score < vAux[j+1].score) then
            begin
                swap(vAux[j],vAux[j+1]);
                sorted:=false;
            end;
            inc(j);
        end;
        inc(i);
    end;
end;
```

The code itself is part of a really big source file, I can post the whole thing but the responsible for the error is just that bunch of lines. The debugger terminates at line:

```
swap(vAux[j],vAux[j+1]);
```

tplayers is just a type defined as an array of records that contain score (an integer) among a bunch of other variables. trplayers is the type of the aforementioned records. I'm at a total loss; FPC (while not under debugging mode) spits an out-of-range error but under my watches I see that the variables I'm trying to read exist. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: First of all, where's the array declaration ? second if you're getting vAux as input, why are you doing **vAux:=tplayers;** at the beginning ?

Comment: @Yochai: Sorry about that, my original code is in Spanish so I thought I'd better translate some of the variables and got that one mixed up. The array is declared as tplayers=array[1..MAXPLAYERS] of trplayers. trplayers is just a record containing some integer values such as score.

Comment: Please post your actual code, without worrying about translation. Variable names shouldn't really matter, and trying to change it to post here often introduces errors (like what happened here) that changes or hides the actual problem.

Comment: Better, a minimal runnable program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`rAux:trplayers;` have you typed a wrong symbol or the type here really contains "r" in its name?

Comment: No, that's correct, it's a record; tvplayers is an array of trplayers.

Comment: `procedure swap(var a:tplayers;var b:tplayers);` `rAux:trplayers;` `rAux:=a;` You obviously should have a type mismatch error during the compilation. I haven't found `tvplayers` in your code. Is here the code that you really execute? Check it out one more time, please.

Comment: You're right, I translated the types and variable names to English so it could be easier to understand. a and b are trplayers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks valid (other than typos) ... so let's try something simple.
What's the value of "j" when you abort?
If the debugger won't tell you, try adding:

```
writeln ('j = ', j);
```

just before the "swap" call.

As Yochai's question implied, your array needs to be dimensioned at least from
1 (or lower) to MAXPLAYERS (or larger).  (I.e.: 0..MAXPLAYERS-1 would not work,
but 1..MAXPLAYERS should.)

Comment: The array subscripts are correct, since the loop uses `vAux[j]` and `vAux[j + 1]`. You have to limit it to `MAXPLAYERS - 1`, or the second condition (`vAux[j + 1]`)  would go beyond the end of the array.

Comment: In the comments of the post the OP specifies the range of the array 1..MAXPLAYERS, so that is not the problem. I agree with Stan that looking what the indices are just before the exception is the clue to solution